# Reusing one method with more than one property

Tags: c#, properties

Lately I ran in this programming problem. I want to reuse this one "Average" method a lot of times, but with different integer properties. I tried surfing through internet, searching for something similar, but I found nothing. 
So i would like to ask you for a little help. Maybe you could suggest me something more useful or maybe this type of problem solving for this situation is not suited at all?

```
public double CountAverage(NameOfTheProperty)
{
    double Average = 0;
    double Amount = 0;

    foreach (Athlete athlete in this.Athletes)
    {
        Amount += athlete.NameOfTheProperty;
    }

    return Average;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually this is solved with a function. In your case, there is already a LINQ function to do so (called `Average`), but to show you how it works:

```
public double CountAverage(Func<Athlete, double> func)
{
    double Average = 0;
    double Amount = 0;

    foreach (Athlete athlete in this.Athletes)
    {
        Amount += func(athlete);
    }

    return Amount / this.Athletes.Count;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
double d = CountAverage(a => a.NameOfProperty);
```

The LINQ version:

```
double d = this.Athletes.Average(a => a.NameOfProperty);
```